# add an element to json object using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json string imported from a URL request. I need to insert an element to the existing object using python.

Here is my json file:

```
{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key1": value, "key2": value, "key3": -5, "key4": "key5", "key6": [{"key7": value, "key8": value}]}, "key9": "value"}
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key1": value, "key2": value, "key3": -5, "key4": "key5", "key6": [{"key7": value, "key8": value}]}, "key9": "value", "new_key": "new_value"}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on Python 3.6+ you can do the following. Note that the JSON values are strings rather than the dicts you posted.

```
import json

old = '{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key1": "value", "key2": "value", "key3": -5, "key4": "key5", "key6": [{"key7": 1542603600, "key8": 94}]}, "key9": "OK"}'

new = json.dumps({**json.loads(old), **{"new_key": "new_value"}})

>>> new
'{"status_code": 200, "data": {"key1": "value", "key2": "value", "key3": -5, "key4": "key5", "key6": [{"key7": 1542603600, "key8": 94}]}, "key9": "OK", "new_key": "new_value"}'
```

If pre 3.6 you need to store the dict someplace to update

```
temp = json.loads(old)
temp.update({"new_key": "new_value"})
new = json.dumps(temp)
```

Comment: This works fine! Thanks :)